# Is there a way to ignore broadcasted UDP messages with DatagramSocket in Java on Windows?

Tags: java, sockets, broadcast

I am looking for a way to not receive broadcast messages with [DatagramSocket](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html). The implementation seems to hide the destination address so I cannot use that as a filter. Setting setBroadcast seems to do nothing.

I have a socket bound in a local ip address but it still receives all the broadcast messages from the subnet.

```
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("1.2.3.4");
InetSocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(addr, 12345);
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(sockaddr);
```

What would be the easiest way to filter the broadcast messages and only receive messages sent directly to my ip?

EDIT: The short answer is no. This question stemmed from an architecture where we had custom routing of UDP messages and some nodes in the subnet were not necessarily broadcasting or interested in the broadcasts. There were other issues with it and we ended up modifying the architecture a bit.

Comment: Doesn't look like Java exposes a way to set the IP_PKTINFO option or a recvmsg() equivalent. (Which is how to do this with native sockets). Why do you want to filter out *just* broadcast traffic?  If this is some sort of "filter out broadcast noise for security" purpose, you would still have to deal with directed packets from unauthorized nodes.. What is your scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [simple Java application using UDP packets](http://www.cs.uic.edu/~troy/spring05/cs450/sockets/UDPClient.java) that shows using the DatagramPacket class to send and received UDP datagrams and querying the various fields such as the sender's IP address.  So if you can use the IP address of the sender as an indication as to whether the message should be processed or ignored, this should help you out.

If you are using class DatagramSocket, the UDP datagram received includes the header information and you can parse it out according to this [DatagramSocket documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html).  This article from [wikipedia on User Datagram Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) discusses the UDP datagram format and structure.

So the question is whether you can have a list of allowed senders of messages or some way to filter out not allowed senders.

Another option would be to provide some kind of identification information or signature in the datagram that will allow you to identify allowed datagrams versus those to be ignored.  You do not mention the types of broadcasts but perhaps you can ignore anything that is less than a specified number of bytes or something similar.  Or perhaps you can ignore any datagrams from a certain range of ports or allow only datagrams from a specific range of ports.